# SVN/subversion: How to get a zipped file $Revision $ tag updated at commit time?

Tags: svn

With a pending third party application upgrade the .xml files that contain our "$Revision$" tag will now be packaged in a zip file at commit time.  How can I get the revision number in the xml file in the zip file updated at commit time or the zip file itself tagged?

Thanks

Comment: You could also add revision number to the archive filename

Comment: you know, what svn-keyword inside **file** will reflect **last changes of this file**, not *repository globally*?

Answer (score 0):

SubWCRev if Windows or svnrev if Linux and post-commit hook (for revision-based filename)

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize your build system to take the svn revision number as an argument.  Then it should checkout that revision, and have the revision number available to all the other build / packaging steps.

This makes your "build the latest" rule the same as your "build an old release" rule.  The only difference is that you run `svnrev` once, at the beginning of the build.  If you run `svnrev` multiple times, or if you run it after checking out the latest revision, you can introduce issues when your repository is encountering a heavy check-in rate.  Basically you might mis-label the zip file with the "latest" revision number, which would be "newer" than the code you checked out.